# what's the default path of outputStreamWriter.write(data);?

Tags: file, path

What's the default path where a file will be written if I use "outputStreamWriter.write(data);"?

There was no error occured so the file must have been written. But where? I can't find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've used a *relative* path with an underlying `FileOutputStream` somewhere "beyond" that `outputStreamWriter`, it's based on whatever the current directory was when you opened the file for output. Usually, this is the directory you were in when the program started, assuming you're not changing it.

If you *are* changing it, it will be based on whatever the current directory was when the `OutputStreamWriter` object (or, more precisely, the underlying `FileOutputStream` object) opened the file.

Of course, if you've used an *absolute* path to open the file, it'll be wherever you told it to be.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should better use a specified file path. Thanks!